# Java cannot use logback inside JAR

Tags: java

I am trying to use logback while running my ap outside of project ( inside the JAR file ). I have tried to move it in the root folder and run it with the following command:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/logback.xml -jar xxxxx.jar
```

but it didn't work.When I am running the project from `intelliJ` everything work as expecte but when I build the artifacts it doesn't work anymore.

I am using JavaFX with dependencies, I don't use maven.

My Logback xml file is this:

```
<configuration>

    <timestamp key="TIMESTAMP" datepattern="HHmmss"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${user.home}/vlcj-${TIMESTAMP}.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-36(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %72logger{72} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-36(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %72logger{72} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="ch" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com" level="ERROR"/>

    <logger name="uk.co.caprica.vlcj" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I get the following error:

```
10:43:01,092 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT
 find resource [logback.groovy]
10:43:01,092 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found res
ource [logback-test.xml] at [jar:file:/D:/DigiStorageStreamer/out/artifacts/Digi
StorageStreamer/DigiStorageStreamer.jar!/logback-test.xml]
10:43:01,099 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@6af6
b7d7 - URL [jar:file:/D:/DigiStorageStreamer/out/artifacts/DigiStorageStreamer/D
igiStorageStreamer.jar!/logback-test.xml] is not of type file
10:43:01,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -
 debug attribute not set
10:43:01,127 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Attri
bute named [datePattern] cannot be empty
10:43:01,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Using
current interpretation time, i.e. now, as time reference.
10:43:01,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About t
o instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
10:43:01,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming
appender as [FILE]
10:43:01,144 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA
- Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] fo
r [encoder] property
10:43:01,161 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is
 set to [C:\Users\Marian Pavel/vlcj-TIMESTAMP_IS_UNDEFINED.log]
10:43:01,163 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About t
o instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:43:01,163 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming
appender as [CONSOLE]
10:43:01,164 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA
- Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] fo
r [encoder] property
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Settin
g level of logger [ch] to ERROR
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Settin
g level of logger [org] to ERROR
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Settin
g level of logger [com] to ERROR
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Settin
g level of logger [uk.co.caprica.vlcj] to DEBUG
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Se
tting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
10:43:01,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Atta
ching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
10:43:01,166 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Atta
ching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
10:43:01,166 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -
 End of configuration.
10:43:01,166 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2ffd1032 -
 Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

10:43:01.221 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO
                uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - vlcj: 3.9.0
10:43:01.223 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO
                uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java: 1.8.0_66 Oracle Corporation
10:43:01.223 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO
                uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.
8.0_66
10:43:01.224 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO
                uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - os: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
Unable to load library 'libvlc': JNA native support (win32-amd64/libvlc.dll) not
 found in resource path (DigiStorageStreamer.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:220)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:322)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:142)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:387)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:366)
        at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc.<clinit>(LibVlc.java:115)
        at Player.<init>(Player.java:72)
        at Main$1.handle(Main.java:86)
        at Main$1.handle(Main.java:63)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.
run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.
run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent
$353(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? please update the question with the errors you get.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Your command line parameter is `-Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/logback.xml` but he log says it finds the xml file in `D:/DigiStorageStreamer/out/artifacts/Digi
StorageStreamer/DigiStorageStreamer.jar!/logback-test.xml`, i.e. not in the conf directory. Is there a logback-test.xml file in the root of your jar?

Comment: Yes there is, that's what I don't understand.

Comment: no, that normal behaviour. logback checks always if there is a logback-test-xml. the loglevel is "INFO" only. the error is: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Attri
bute named [datePattern] cannot be empty. change your " <timestamp key="TIMESTAMP" datepattern="HHmmss"/>" in the xml to "datePattern" with upper case "P"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your " `<timestamp key="TIMESTAMP" datepattern="HHmmss"/>`" in the xml to "`datePattern`" with uppercase "P"

Answer (score -1):

Could you try full path logback.xml and place logback.xml outside Jar?